# Mac roaming profile on a Windows 2008 domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, osx-mountain-lion, active-directory, roaming-profiles

Have been pointed here by the guys at ServerFault - hoping this is the right forum (it seems to fit in with the guidelines).

I'm setting up a home network with Windows 2008 R2 server. I've configured active directory so that user shares are saved on a separate NAS device referenced through DFS. My Windows machines are successfully logging on and saving their data appropriately.

I also have a mac laptop (running mountain lion), which I wish to connect to the network. I've bound it to the domain successfully and can log in, however I'm having difficulty in seeing the user's folders.

Following various guides on the net, I've set up the account on the server with a home folder drive mapping. If I turn off the "mobile account" option in Directory Services on the mac and log in, I can see my network home folder on the dock, which is great, but isn't available offline (for obvious reasons).

If I turn on the "mobile account" option and log in, the home folder does not appear and everything is simply saved locally.

As it's a laptop, I really want the roaming profile capability.  It feels like this should be available and I'm just messing something up with the configuration.  It doesn't look like an authentication problem - in both set ups, I can manually navigate to the folders on the network and see the files.

Any suggestions / feedback very gratefully received.

As a "nice to have", I'd also like to map the various "Documents", "Pictures" etc folders to their equivalent on the Windows account.  I appreciate this may be optimistic, but would be interested to know any details on this as well.

**Update:** Have discovered that the use of a DFS reference in the account profile probably wasn't helping.  I've replaced this with the SMB reference to the home folder.  When I log in now with mobile accounts enabled, I see the folder on the dock.  That's the good news, the bad news is that I don't seem to have a mobile account.  If I save there, it goes to the network.  If I save to my home folder or Documents on Finder, it puts it on the local hard drive.

Worse though, is I don't seem to be able to log in if I'm not connected to the network - I've changed my client DNS settings to hide the server.  I can still see the user account on the mac (like it's got a working roaming profile), but entering the password causes a long delay, followed by a failure to log in (password box shakes and resets).